# How can someone show the element x on hover of element y and place it next to it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I struggle with linking one (tooltip) element to another element. The tooltip element should show up once the user hovers the other element.

My idea is to set up a jQuery hover function accordingly to manipulate the display property.

**So my questions basically are**

1. How to structure this kind of function in jQuery? Right now there is no effect at all when hovering, even when I just try `alert("Test")` on hover. It seems the created elements are not recognized by the mouse pointer.
2. How to place the tooltip element next to the initial element when hovering? (Right now the tooltip elements are hidden by default and don't take any place in the HTML body)

**This is the JS part, where no hover effect is showing yet (example with one tooltip)**

```
$( "#id10" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( "#tooltip10" ).removeAttr("display");
  }, function() {
    $( "#tooltip10" ).css( "display:none" );
  }
);
```

**And the loop part which works pretty fine:**

```
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    async: "True",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/team/" + team_id,
    success: function(response) {

      $('.datapoint').remove();

      var responseData = response.api.fixtures;

      $.each(responseData, function(i) {

        if (team_id == response.api.fixtures[i].homeTeam.team_id) {
          var teamData = home;
        } else {
          var teamData = away;
        }

        if (response.api.fixtures[i].goalsHomeTeam > response.api.fixtures[i].goalsAwayTeam && teamData == home) {
          var resultDataPoint = '<div class="datapointgreen datapoint"' + 'id=id' + response.api.fixtures[i].fixture_id + '"></div>';
        } else if (response.api.fixtures[i].goalsHomeTeam > response.api.fixtures[i].goalsAwayTeam && teamData == away) {
          var resultDataPoint = '<div class="datapointred datapoint"' + 'id=id' + response.api.fixtures[i].fixture_id + '"></div>';
        } else if (response.api.fixtures[i].goalsHomeTeam < response.api.fixtures[i].goalsAwayTeam && teamData == away) {
          var resultDataPoint = '<div class="datapointgreen datapoint"' + 'id=id' + response.api.fixtures[i].fixture_id + '"></div>';
        } else if (response.api.fixtures[i].goalsHomeTeam < response.api.fixtures[i].goalsAwayTeam && teamData == home) {
          var resultDataPoint = '<div class="datapointred datapoint"' + 'id=id' + response.api.fixtures[i].fixture_id + '"></div>';
        } else {
          var resultDataPoint = '<div class="datapointblue datapoint"' + 'id=id' + response.api.fixtures[i].fixture_id + '"></div>';
        }

      // create tooltip container

      var tooltip = $('<table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip' + response.api.fixtures[i].fixture_id +
       '"><tr><td>Hometeam</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.api.fixtures[i].goalsAwayTeam + '</td>' +
        '<td>3 (1)</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>hometeam</td>' +
        '<td>' + response.api.fixtures[i].goalsHomeTeam + '</td>' +
        '<td>2 (1)</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Venue</td>' +
        '<td>Emirates</td></tr>' +
        '</table>`');

      $('.resultData').append(tooltip);

      $('.resultData').append(resultDataPoint);

      });
```

**Some illustration:**

[image]

**Reproducible code snippet:**

```js
$("#id10").hover(
  function() {
    $("#tooltip10").css("display", null);
  },
  function() {
    $("#tooltip10").css("display", "none");
  }
);
```

```css
#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip10">
      <tr>
        <td>Hometeam</td>
        <td> Test </td>
        <td>3 (1)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hometeam</td>
        <td> Test </td>
        <td>2 (1)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Venue</td>
        <td>Emirates</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>

  </div>

</body>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: One thing: `display` is not an attribute of the element. It is a property of the style of the element. So you can't use `removeAttr` to remove it. You can just set it to null using `css("display", null)`. That leads to the misuse of `css()` in the `else` branch; it should be `css("display", "none")`. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Regarding the remainder of the question; you'll really need to show the HTML on which this code is running. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a [mre] to the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out, I fixed it accordingly. Also I spotted that in the datapoint id there was a double " included which I also fixed. Still, no party on hover.. will add a reproducible shortly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I included the code snippet. Sorry for being such late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Elements are dynamically rendered so you can use `$(document).on("mouseover","element",(){})` and `$(document).on("mouseleave","element",(){})`

You can use `show()` and `hide()`(to show and hide tooltip) functions simply,

As Following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("mouseover","#id10",function() {
      $("#tooltip10").show();
  });
    $(document).on("mouseleave","#id10",function() {
      $("#tooltip10").hide();
  });
})
```

```css
#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
    <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip10">
      <tr>
        <td>Hometeam</td>
        <td> Test </td>
        <td>3 (1)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hometeam</td>
        <td> Test </td>
        <td>2 (1)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Venue</td>
        <td>Emirates</td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>

</body>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Still no action in my environment tough, hmh. You didnt change the css html part, right? ...Even when i force state: hover in the dev tools the tooltip won't show up. But when i remove the display class it shows up, so it isn't a z-index issue.

Comment: Now that works. Thank you. But could you explain me the difference why show/hide doesn't work on dynamically rendered DOMs?

Comment: show/hide works but `$(element).hover` doesnt work for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with:

```
$("#id10").hover(
    function() {
        $("#tooltip10").css("display", "block");
    },
    function() {
        $("#tooltip10").css("display", "none");
    }
);
```

then i made a little correction to you CSS:

```
#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
 }

#mainContent .resultData {
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
    margin-left: 12px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #00DC8E;
}
```

And finally your template:

```
<body>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <table class="resultData tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip10">
      <tr>
        <td>Hometeam</td>
        <td> Test </td>
        <td>3 (1)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hometeam</td>
        <td> Test </td>
        <td>2 (1)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Venue</td>
        <td>Emirates</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

A working example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08yo61wr/)